# x64 Assembly modulo not working right

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, division, modulo

I am trying to implement modulo using x64 Assembly, but as it seems it is not working right. I tried to write the code below using x86 Assembly and it worked okay, but my task is to do it in x64.

```
mov rdx, 0
mov rax, 1234
mov rbx, 10
div rbx
push rdx
push dword message3
call _printf
add rsp, 8
```

For the example above I get rdx=3 instead of expected 4. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You get 4 in `rdx`. The calling convention is unusual for the common 64-bit ABIs, what ABI is your code conforming to?

Comment: Why am I getting output 3 when I try to print it then? What do you mean by ABI? sorry I'm new to this stuff :/

Comment: I agree with Margeret, you should end up with 4 in RDX.  If you step through the code with a debugger,  I'm (she) are pretty sure that's what you will see.  That suggests your call to printff isn't doing what you think it is.   An apparant bug may occur because your code is buggy, or because what you are using to see what the code is doing is defective.  I think the latter explains your problem.  Welcome to debugging, where you can't trust anything.  (I've even encountered defective debuggers).

Comment: [`PUSH r/m32`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PUSH.html) is not even encodeable in x86-64, so what does your assembler emit when you feed it `push dword message3`?  Anyway, if you're looking at what printf actually prints, it's a miracle that it prints anything after you call it with a small integer in RDX instead of a pointer to a format string.  Unless you've invented your own weird x86-64 calling convention that passes all args on the stack like obsolete 32-bit calling conventions, and implemented printf for it...  See the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for links

Comment: Oh actually, doesn't the x86-64 Windows calling convention want the args pre-stored in the shadow space for varags functions?  In that case you might just have lucked out, if your assembler happens to assemble that `push` to a 64-bit PUSH instead of the requested impossible 32-bit PUSH.  Anyway `add rsp, 8` is obviously still wrong, because 2 * 8 = 16, not 8.

Comment: What is ABI: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/x86/3261/calling-conventions#t=201611211319464320592  (search for your target platform .. if it is not there, search on Internet).